# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'username')

Tags: javascript, node.js

hello i got this problem . And i still not find out my issue. thanks you for helping me
this is code of login.js

```
    var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var db=require('../database');
/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('login');
});

router.post('/login', function(req, res){
    var username = req.body.username;
    var password = req.body.password;

    var sql='SELECT * FROM users WHERE username =? AND password =?';
    db.query(sql, [username, password], function (err, data, fields) {
        if(err) throw err
        if(data.length>0){
            req.session.loggedinUser= true;
            req.session.username= username;
            res.redirect('/dashboard');
        }else{
            res.render('login',{alertMsg:"Your username or password is wrong"});
        }
    })

})

module.exports = router;
```

and this is my login page (

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  
</head>
<body>
<div class="login-form">
  <h3>Login Form</h3>
<p><%=(typeof alertMsg!='undefined')? alertMsg:''%></p>
<form method="post" action="/login">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" required">
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" required">
       <button type="submit">Login Now</button>
       <a href="/register">New Registration</a>
  </div>
</form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and when i enter username and password and click login button it get this error :

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'username')

[Image of the error . Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JafKO.png)

Im happy if you can help me

Comment: Where does this error occur? At which line?

Comment: when i press login page . it show that error

Comment: You don't have set up [`express.json`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.json), which is used to parse the POST request payload and provide `req.body` with its properties. So, the payload is not properly parsed, which is why there is no username property in `req.body`.